# deny specific file extension in proftpd

Tags: proftpd

user's ftp points to /mnt/ftp/user
I want to deny uploading of .jpg extension via ftp to his directory (and for subdirectories too.) I found something like PathAllowFilter but it allows specific exntensions but I need to allow all extensions except .jpg.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can use the [`PathDenyFilter`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_core.html#PathDenyFilter) directive, like the following.  Since you mentioned wanting to impose this restriction for a given user (say, user "foo"), and in their directory, I would suggest putting this directive in a `<Directory>` section:

```
<Directory /mnt/ftp/foo>
  # Deny .jpg files.  Watch for upper/lower cases!
  PathDenyFilter \.jpg$ [nocase]
</Directory>
```

Hope this helps!